# Expanding lists push other relative positioned elements up - they should stay still

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let me start off with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lwhpgmma/

Basically I have some list items like this:

```
    <ul class="specifics">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Filter by Hosting</li>
                <li data-value="ghost" class="active">Ghost Host</li>
                <li data-value="they">They Host</li>
                <li data-value="you">You Host</li>
                <li data-value="server">Server</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Filter by Game Mode</li>
                <li data-value="1" class="active">Soccar</li>
                <li data-value="2">Snowday</li>
                <li data-value="3">Hoops</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The inner `<ul>` is hidden via `line-height: 0;` on the parent `<li>` element. However, when an `<li>` element is clicked, the `.active` class is added and it gets set to `line-height: normal;`

This all works fine, except that it causes some ugly results when these first-tier `<li>` elements are stacked on-top of each other, like they are in the fiddle demo.

You'll notice when you click `Manfield` or `$100` list elements, that the list elements above them (`Server` and `Soccar`) get pushed up. They should stay in the same place they currently are, and the menu from the active `<li>` should simply flow over the other inactive `<li>` elements.

I tried changing the first-tier elements from `<li>` to `<span>` which solved the issue of the top options bringing their horizontal siblings along for the ride, but doesn't solve the issue of the bottom elements pushing their upper siblings when they expand.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please include all the logic of your issue in your question, rather than linking to off site resources.  You can edit your question and type Ctrl+M to bring up the on site editor to create a working example of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Positioning for this and instead of `overflow` use flexbox, like:

```
.dot-overflow {
  position: relative;
}

.dot-overflow.active ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #0F1316;
}

/* Make it a flex container */
ul.specifics {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below (*use full screen to see it properly*):

```js
// handle the specifics dropdowns
var allSpecifics = $('ul.specifics > li');
$(document).on('click', 'ul.specifics > li', function(event) {
  var openThis = ($(this).hasClass('active')) ? false : true;
  allSpecifics.removeClass('active');
  if (openThis)
    $(this).addClass('active');
  else {
    // selected an option
    $(event.target).closest('li[data-value]').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }
}).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('ul.specifics > li').length || $(event.target).closest('ul.specifics > li.active > ul > li:first-of-type').length) {
    allSpecifics.removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.specifics-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul.specifics {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.specifics > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 1px #010;
  /*border-right: 1px ridge rgba(225, 255, 225, 0.165);*/
  padding: 9px 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 24.5%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #13141c;
  transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease;
}

ul.specifics > li > i {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 11px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.3);
}

ul.specifics > li > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 420px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.specifics > li.active > ul {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul.specifics > li > ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* this is added to the remodal open() function */
  width: 0;
  /* remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

ul.specifics > li > ul > li {
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease;
}

ul.specifics > li > ul > li:first-of-type {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ccc;
}

ul.specifics > li > ul > li.active {
  line-height: normal;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #ddd;
}

ul.specifics > li.active > ul > li {
  line-height: normal;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 16px 0;
}

ul.specifics > li.active > ul > li:first-of-type {
  padding: 6px 0;
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

ul.specifics > li.active > ul > li.active {
  background: rgba(0, 91, 36, 0.15);
}

ul.specifics > li.active > ul > li:hover {
  color: #ddd;
  background: rgba(0, 31, 96, 0.1);
}

ul.specifics > li.active > ul > li:first-of-type:hover {
  background: none;
}

ul.specifics > li.active > i {
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.specifics > li:last-of-type {
  /*border-right: none;*/
}

ul.specifics > li:hover {
  background: #1b1d24;
}

ul.specifics > li.active > ul > li:first-of-type:before {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  content: "\00d7";
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.40s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.40s ease;
}

ul.specifics > li.active > ul > li:first-of-type:hover:before {
  color: red;
}


@media (max-width: 991px) {
  ul.specifics {
    background: #13141c;
  }
  ul.specifics > li {
    width: 49.5%;
  }
}

.dot-overflow {
  position: relative;
}

.dot-overflow.active ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #0F1316;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="specifics-container">
  <ul class="specifics">
    <li class="dot-overflow">
      <i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>
      <ul>
        <li>Filter by Hosting</li>
        <li data-value="ghost" class="active">Ghost Host</li>
        <li data-value="they">They Host</li>
        <li data-value="you">You Host</li>
        <li data-value="server">Server</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dot-overflow">
      <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
      <ul>
        <li>Filter by Game Mode</li>
        <li data-value="1" class="active">Soccar</li>
        <li data-value="2">Snowday</li>
        <li data-value="3">Hoops</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dot-overflow">
      <i class="fa fa-map"></i>
      <ul>
        <li>Filter by Map</li>
        <li data-value="248" class="active">Manfield</li>
        <li data-value="1337" i>Wasteland</li>
        <li data-value="421">Utopia</li>
        <li data-value="121">Stadium</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dot-overflow">
      <i class="fa fa-ticket"></i>
      <ul>
        <li>Filter by League</li>
        <li data-value="100" class="active">$100</li>
        <li data-value="50">$50</li>
        <li data-value="20">$20</li>
        <li data-value="5">$5</li>
        <li data-value="1">$1</li>
        <li data-value=".5">50¢</li>
        <li data-value="0">Free</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its my pleasure @DanL

Comment: Actually, it exhibits odd behavior in wide screen when they are all on the same row. can you please verify this?

Comment: @DanL When you again click on the option every thing again goes up and comes down with the list. This is because as soon as you select the option the `.active` class is removed from the `.dot-overflow` and all my css rules written for `.dot-overflow.active` becomes invalid. You can solve it using JS. Just make a condition to not to remove the `.active` class until the dropdown menu is fully closed. Hope you understand. But why you unaccepted the answer :(